# Center toastr notifications within a div

Tags: asp.net, css, toastr

I'm trying to get my [toastr notification](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/) to show up in the middle of a div. I've seen some suggestions, like [this one](http://www.johnpapa.net/centering-toastr-with-css/), but it's centering based on the overall window, and not within a div.

Is it possible to center a toast notification within a form element, when toastr knows nothing about the elements on a form?

My latest attempt was to roughly center the toast within the page, but I'd like to center it within a certain div. Is that possible? If so, how?

This is my centering attempt:

```
.toast-center {
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can try to create a new div and position it in the center of your expected div.

Then you can use `positionClass` option of toastr which is the location for your notification to popup

```
toastr.options: {
    "positionClass": "your-newly-created-div-class"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do everything you just suggested. Let me work through it and see. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: @Bob Horn, check [this](https://johnpapa.net/centering-toastr-with-css/) article, it explains.

Comment: I think this is at least half the answer, the other half maybe being the `containerId` option? Check its use in toastr.js [here](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/f6fb3e3b4e0e237c1ba6c159e170c442daee1dc3/toastr.js#L58). If you use `containerId` to make the frame of reference the form, then `positionClass` to position it in the middle, does that work?

Answer (score 5):

In toastr.css,add this:

```
.toast-top-center {
    top: 12px;
    left:50%;
    margin:0 0 0 -150px;
}
```

And in JavaScript,use this:

```
toastr.options = {
    positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
};
```

If your toast div has some other width,you can modify the CSS above to the half width of it.

```
margin:0 0 0 (here caculate the -width/2 px for yourself)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with jquery

In toastr.css,add this:

```
.toast-top-center { 
   top: 12px;   
   margin: 0 auto;  
   left: 50%;   
   margin-left: -150px;
 }
```

in js file add this after:

```
toastr.options = {
    positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
};

toastr.success("Your Message Header", "Your Message");

var $notifyContainer = $('#toast-container').closest('.toast-top-center');
if ($notifyContainer) {
   // align center
   var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 90;
   $notifyContainer.css("margin-top", windowHeight / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a native solution for this problem in the last versions of ngx-toastr (^14.1.4), if you check the toast.css file you can see the following:

```css
.toast-center-center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

So you only have to use `{positionClass: 'toast-center-center' }` in your .ts when you are calling the toastr notification

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet tested in angular ~9.1.0 with **"ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0"**.

**component-name.ts**

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-name',
  templateUrl: './component-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-name.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentName implements OnInit {
 
    constructor(private readonly toastrService: ToastrService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.toastrService.toastrConfig.positionClass = 'toast-top-center';
      }
}
```

**component-name.scss**

```
.toast-top-center { 
    top: 12px;   
    margin: 0 auto;  
    left: 50%;   
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css style sheet:

```
.toast-top-center {
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 -150px !important;
}
```

In jQuery file:

```
  if (data.reminderNote !== "") {
                                toastr.options = {
                                    'debug': false,
                                    'positionClass': 'toast-top-center',
                                    'closeButton': true,
                                    'preventDuplicates': false,
                                    'showDuration': '1000',
                                    'hideDuration': '1000',
                                    'timeOut': '5000',
                                    'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
                                    'showEasing': 'swing',
                                    'hideEasing': 'linear',
                                    'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
                                    'hideMethod': 'fadeOut',
                                };
                                toastr.error(data.reminderNote);
                            }
```